# How to use Bootstrapper Manifest Generator

Tags: bootstrapping

I have been able to add installers and build it generates product named xml with sole files now what to do?

Should i include that xml to my visual studio setup project?

so that the setup created is a one click installer means i have to run it only rest of pre req will installed automatically by the bootstrapper i generated

Comment: Did you try Bootstrapper Manifest Generator? http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/bmg

Answer (score -2):

You'd better investigate how the Paint.NET installer doing.

It's open source.